# Balls collision detection - radius calculation - nearly done

Tags: java, android, collision

Hello :) I'm totally lost. I have two balls on the screen, floating. Also I have a method that checks is there is a collision and a method name 'collide' that collides :)

When both balls goes in a straight line on each other it collides well. The problem is shown on the picture:
[image]

So, the methods are:

```
public final float ball_radius = 2.4f; // ball image has 48 width
public boolean isColliding(Ball ball)
{
    distance = Math.sqrt((ball.image_center_x - this.image_center_x)*(ball.image_center_x - this.image_center_x)+(ball.image_center_y - this.image_center_y)*(ball.image_center_y - this.image_center_y));
    if(distance <= 2*ball_radius)
        return true;
    /*
    float sumRadius = 9.6f;
    float sqrRadius = sumRadius * sumRadius;

    float distSqr = (xd * xd) + (yd * yd);

    if (distSqr <= sqrRadius)
    {
        return true;
    }*/

    return false;
}

 void Collide(Ball ball1, Ball ball2)
{
    double dx = (ball1.x - ball2.x) + dt * (ball1.vx - ball2.vx);
    double dy = (ball1.y - ball2.y) + dt * (ball1.vy - ball2.vy);

    // if collision swap velocities
    if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) <= 2*ball_radius) {
        double tempx = ball1.vx;
        double tempy = ball1.vy;
        ball1.vx = ball2.vx;
        ball1.vy = ball2.vy;
        ball2.vx = tempx;
        ball2.vy = tempy;
    }
}

   private  void moveBalls(){
    for (int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) {
        Ball ball1 = balls.get(i);
        for (int a = i + 1; a < balls.size(); a++) {
            Ball ball2 = balls.get(a);
           if(ball1.isColliding(ball2)) {
               ball1.Collide(ball1, ball2);
               checkHealthAndChangeColor(ball1, ball2);
           }
                //catchMP.start();
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) {
        balls.get(i).step();
    }
}
```

Comment: @FrankN.Stein 
But when I have a 48/48 picture with a ball that means that the ball has a radius = 24. When we get the distance between first ball center point and the second center point and check the difference it should work O.o. I think that

Comment: Gather collision surface,  reflect balls over that surface using the collision angle or normal of surface.

Comment: Just to clarify - you say the ball image width is 48, but you set the radius to `2.4f`. Shouldn't it be `24f`?

Comment: `IsColliding` looks correct, I think that the problem is in the method `Collide`, why are you taking in account the "next" ball position if they are colliding "now" (you already checked that)?

Comment: Cinnam the screen is like 100f/100f - I don't understand how this works, to be honest :D. I've just check that if I put a ball on (50f, 97.6f) it's well placed on center bottom (it's touching the screen's edge) - that's why it has 4.8f. Yes, you're right :)

@huseyintugrulbuyukisik the collision works - balls are floating in a right direction after it happens, but checking doesn't work well.

AndreaGhidini
there was just a second check - removed it now, but it changes nothing. They still overlap themselves.

Comment: http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/when-worlds-collide-simulating-circle-circle-collisions--gamedev-769

Comment: @FrankN.Stein these algorithms are just like mine.

I think the problem is with the pictures, something with height and width. Dunno :(

Comment: Can you log what's happening?

Comment: @Cinnam https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTyOGf2MOes&feature=youtu.be

First throw is good, they're on a straight line.
At 20-24 secs it's well shown what's wrong.

Comment: Oh, I meant log some output/values/debug info into a file. But thanks for the video as well :)

Comment: Log won't give you anything. It's something messed with these positions (center and actual) :(

Comment: That's the point - you could log those to see what their values are in various methods. I'm not familiar with android emulators, can you output to `System.out` or something?

Comment: Okay I solved this by rewriting the whole positioning system (it was in percentages, not it's just on pixels and screen width/height). 

They key is here that the formula is correct :)

Thanks to everyone! :)